# Indexes for where clause and join clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Consider the following:

- Table1 with following columns: a, b, m
- Table2 with following columns: a, b, x, y

And this is my query:

```
select t2.a, t2.b, t1.m
from table2 t2
join table1 t1 on t1.a = t2.a 
              and t2.b = t2.b
where t2.x = 'some value'
  and t2.y = 'some other value'
```

I have to optimize this query.

I have the following non-clustered indices:

- index on table1, with column a and b
- index on table2, with column a
  and b
- index on table2, with column x and y

Would I benefit from another index on table2 that would cover all the columns used in this query: a, b, x and y?

Comment: I think that you could consider to include the column `m` in the index on `table1` (as an included column)

Comment: @Lamak, yes, I get that. My actual query is more complex than the simple example. I am more interested on the indices on Table2. Are the two 'existing' indices enough, or should I create an extra one with all 4 columns?

Comment: The optimizer will only use one index per table when coming up with a query plan. You want to make sure that index is useful. This may depend on which table will be scanned versus which will be keyed by index, which can depend on the size of each table. You may need to play around and see which index is being used. Adding additional columns to your index can help making it a "covered query" which can help a bit with IO if no other columns are needed (so the data pages don't need to be dereferenced).

Comment: Approximately how many rows are in each table? Approximately how many rows you expect as the result? Which are the unique keys (defined or possible)?

Comment: There could be millions of rows. I expect one row as the result. The x and y combination will generate a unique result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that the x and y combination will provide a single row, it's important to have an index on table2 on x and y, as well as an index on table1 on a and b. Optionally, you could make the first index unique and add included columns, like this:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_table2_x_y ON table2 (x,y) INCLUDE (a,b)
CREATE INDEX IX_table1_a_b ON table1 (a,b) INCLUDE (m)
```